# Bizarre login failure OS X 10.5 (fixed upon restart, but curious)

Tags: macos, login

I umplugged and moved my iMac (2.16 GHz Intel iMac running 10.5.6) to another room.  When I turned it on, I was locked out of both user accounts.

I am 100% certain that I entered the passwords correctly on both accounts, as I tried each multiple times.

After I restarted the computer from the login screen, my passwords worked.

What in the world could have happened to cause this?  Is it likely to happen again?  Should I have a Linux Live CD waiting just in case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any possibility the keyboard layout may have been switched?  IE, from QWERTY to Dvorak or vice versa?

Comment: I agree that this could have been the issue. This has magically happened to me a few times at the most inopportune password-entry moments. Luckily, it was while I was logged in so that I could see the little Canadian flag turn into a DV when focused on that password field. Weird that it happens at all.

Comment: That must be it.  I use multiple keyboards.  Thanks!